# Is there another way to remove all items of a JComboBox then removeAllItems()?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Is there another way to remove all items of a JComboBox then removeAllItems()? I use 2 JComboBoxes in mij app and when you select an item from the first combobox the related items should then be shown in the second combobox. When I do this, the items just keep appending after the ones that were already there. When I then first try to clear the combobox by using removeAllItems(), the second combobox is empty and stays empty whenever I change the first combobox... The first combobox keeps all its values... Does anyone see my problem?

festival is the JComboBox:

```
private JComboBox festival;
private JComboBox zone;

...

public void fillFestivalList(){
    festival.removeAllItems();
    List festivals = OP.fillFestivalList();

    for(Object fest: festivals)
        festival.addItem(fest.toString());
}

public void fillZoneList(String festival){
    zone.removeAllItems();
    List zones = OP.fillZoneList(festival);

    for(Object zoneItem: zones)
        zone.addItem(zoneItem.toString());
}
```

Comment: Clearly either this isn't the real code or you are calling the wrong method.

Comment: I have just copied the parts that I tought were necessary.. If you want I can add the code you need to solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding,

> Is there another way to remove all items of a JComboBox then removeAllItems()?

Simply give the JComboBox a new model.

I would create a new `DefaultComboBoxModel<T>`, fill it with the newest entries, and then call `setModel(...)` on my JComboBox, passing in the new model when desired.

Comment: So instead of adding the items to the JComboBox zone, I should add them to DefaultComboBoxModel<T> zoneModel and then do zone.setModel(zoneModel)?

Comment: +1, @MaartenMeeusen see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5605775/131872 for a simple example

Answer (score 2):

You can also Remove all the items in this way ,
but better to Give JCombobox a new DefaultComboBoxModel like the way @Hovercraft Full Of Eels said

```
 int itemCount = combo.getItemCount();

        for(int i=0;i<itemCount;i++){
            combo.removeItemAt(0);
         }
```